# react-mic: Recommended Options to Convert weba Audio to MP3, MP4, or WAV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I recently incorporated **react-mic** in my app.  My app uses React on the front-end and Rails on the backend.  While I do love using react-mic, I'm having troubles converting the audio blob to another format - particularly mp3, mp4, or even wav.

I reviewed the react-mic documentation and GitHub issues to see if there were any recommended courses of action, but all I could see is that developers would need to find some solution outside of the library to take care of the conversion.  Also react-mic's author is looking into format conversion options as a future enhancement.  I'm new to all this and would LOVE to hear how others are taking care of this.  Please note the following - my React code takes the audio blob and sends it to my Rails back-end as part of a POST fetch request.  The back-end uses CarrierWave to upload the audio file.  Seeing the popularity of react-mic, I was hoping for guidance on how to take care of the conversion:

Here is my React code using react-mic library:

```
    import React from 'react';
    import { ReactMic } from 'react-mic';

    const hasGetUserMedia = !!(navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia);

    class AudioMic extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
                recordAudio: false,
                blobAudio: null,
                blobURL: null
        };
        };

            startRecording = () => {
            this.setState({
              recordAudio: true
            });
          }

          stopRecording = () => {
            this.setState({
              recordAudio: false
            });
          }

            onStart = () => {
            console.log('You can tap into the onStart callback');
          }

          onStop = (blobAudio) => {
                this.setState({
                    blobAudio: blobAudio,
                    blobURL: blobAudio.blobURL
                });

                this.onUpload();
          };

            onUpload= () => {
                let reader = new FileReader()
                reader.onload = (event) => {
                    //save audio blob in FormData and use FileReader to get into proper format
                    let formData  = new FormData();
                    formData.append('audio', event.target.result);

                    fetch('/api/v1/user_response', {
                        credentials: 'same-origin',
                      method: 'POST',
                      body: formData,
                        headers: {
                            'Accept': 'application/json, */*'
                      }
                    }).then(response => {
                        if (response.ok) {
                            return response;
                        }
                        else {
                            let errorMessage = `${response.status} (${response.statusText})`, error = new Error(errorMessage);
                            throw(error);
                        }
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(body => {
                        console.log('MADE IT HERE');
                        console.log(body);
                    })
                    .catch(error => console.error(`Error in fetch: ${error.message}`));
                };
                reader.readAsDataURL(this.state.blobAudio.blob);
            };

componentDidMount = () => {
        if(!hasGetUserMedia) {
            alert('Your browser cannot stream from your audio. Please switch to Chrome or Firefox.');
        }
    };

render() {
        return (
            <div>
<ReactMic
              className='oscilloscope'
              record={ this.state.recordAudio }
              backgroundColor='#FF4081'
              visualSetting='sinewave'
              audioBitsPerSecond= { 128000 }
              onStop={ this.onStop }
              onStart={ this.onStart }
              strokeColor='#000000'
                    />
            <div>
              <audio ref='audioSource' controls='controls' src={ this.state.blobURL }></audio>
            </div>
                    <Button animated='fade' onClick={ this.startRecording } >
                <Button.Content visible>Start Recording</Button.Content>
                <Button.Content hidden><Icon name='microphone' /></Button.Content>
                </Button>
                    <Button animated='fade' onClick={ this.stopRecording }>
                        <Button.Content visible>Stop Recording</Button.Content>
                        <Button.Content hidden><Icon name='stop' /></Button.Content>
                    </Button>
                    <Button animated='fade' onClick={ this.upload }>
                        <Button.Content visible>Upload Response</Button.Content>
                        <Button.Content hidden><Icon name='cloud upload' /></Button.Content>
                    </Button>
            </div>
        );
    };
};
```

Here is my Rails uploader for the audio file:

```
class UserResponseUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::Audio

  if Rails.env.test?
    storage :file
  else
    storage :fog
  end


  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
end
```

Any suggestions?  I tried using carrierwave-audio to convert to mp3, but I found myself going down a rabbit hole that mentioned using sox for the audio conversion.  Is this something that could be taken care of with another JS library on the front-end?  All help is appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, and it seems you need to pay if you want WAV format. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-mic

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I know this is such an old question but I also greatly struggled with this problem as well. So I think others will benefit from the solution.

The answer is so simple. Let's say you want to convert the audio file to mp3 then all you have to do is add the following code as a property in

`mimeType='audio/mp3'`

Hope this helped at least one person.